# error during running asp.net project using Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, visual-studio-2010

I have this error when i try to debug my asp.net project setting : DEBUG and ANY CPU

error: The file or assembly 'System.Fabric' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. Attempt to load a program with an incorrect format.

STACK TRACE:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Non è stato possibile caricare il file o l'assembly 'BSS.Vortex.AkiteManage.Contracts' o una delle relative dipendenze. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Non è stato possibile caricare il file o l'assembly 'BSS.Vortex.AkiteManage.Contracts' o una delle relative dipendenze. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
```

Comment: Is it possible that your app is 64-bit and that library is only available in 32-bit format?  Try target x86 instead of Any CPU or else check Prefer 32-bit and see whether the issue goes away.

Comment: using x86 it shows the same error but this time with "System.Fabric"

Comment: Are you creating a .NET Core application and trying to reference a .NET Framework DLL?  Is it maybe for an older version of .NET?  I'm not sure what error message you'd get in those cases.

Comment: yes,I'm trying to debug a website project written in asp.net that have a lot of references to other DLL's

Answer (score 0):

> 'System.Fabric' packages are x64 bit, if your system target 32bit it
> will fail.

**So fix the error...**

**Bulid the platform into x64 bit.**

> You have install Nodejs Azure Functions Core Tools from NODC.

*For Download Refer this link..*
https://nodejs.org/en/

After installion, in Command Prompt input npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
So, You azure-functions is permission is enable..

> After this, follow the below step....

- Then set project debug properties(right click on your
  project>Properties>Debug blade).
- Set Launch type to Executable
- Set Executable path to
  %appdata%\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe.
- Add Application arguments start.

  For More Info:-

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b52ec67-13b4-4e6c-8aa6-15e082c001d7/cloud-not-load-systemfabric?forum=AzureServiceFabric